# Sending POJO containing XML Document via Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

i try to post a POJO from one Spring Boot&MVC app to another.
This all works fine except for one case, in which the POJO contains a w3c.dom.Document XML attribute.

The POJO is quite simple, all getters and setters are managed by project lombok:

```java
@Data
public class SmartContractFile {
    private final UUID id;
    private Document file;
    private int copies;

    public SmartContractFile(UUID id, Document scFile, int copies) {
        this.id = id;
        this.file = scFile;
        this.copies = copies;
    }
}
```

The POSTing happens via Spring RestTemplate and contains only the POJO.
I expect a simple true or false response.

```java
    public boolean saveFile(SmartContractFile smartContract) {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        URI methodURI;
        try {
            methodURI = new URI(this.address + DNWebConstants.REST_ADDSC);
            ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = template.postForEntity(methodURI, smartContract, Boolean.class);

            return (response.hasBody() && response.getBody());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The server-side webservice is bound via @RequestMapping and a constant to the target address. I already tried @PostMapping, but the behavior did not change. The POJO should be extracted by Spring via @RequestBody.

```java
@RequestMapping(DNWebConstants.REST_ADDSC)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> addSmartContract(@RequestBody SmartContractFile smartContract) {
        try {
            smartContractHandler.validateScDocument(smartContract.getFile());
        } catch (ContractException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(false);
        }
        if (this.thisNode.saveRequestedScStorage(smartContract))
            return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong storage location.");
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(false);
    }
```

In case of any error in my application, i would always expect a 400 bad request with "false" in the response body, as well as an output on the servers console (either via printStackTrace() or System.out.println()).

However, all i get is a 400 with empty body:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:698) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:484) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at model.Node.saveFile(Node.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
    at model.Topology.saveFile(Topology.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at mgmt.web.DNWebservice.saveSmartContract(DNWebservice.java:111) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

With this being my application:

```
at model.Node.saveFile(Node.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
    at model.Topology.saveFile(Topology.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at mgmt.web.DNWebservice.saveSmartContract(DNWebservice.java:111) ~[classes/:na]
```

Where model.Node.saveFile(Node.java:80) is the client method shown above.

I basically tried every way i know to pack that request and switched wildly through al Spring Annotations, but nothing worked.
So i hope there's somebody here to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found my error, it had nothing to do with the resttemplate.
The bootstrap had an error which caused the app to send the request to itself.
The client denied its' own request and Spring did all the errorhandling automatically, so it did not show in the console output as logged by my application, which is why i overlooked it.

After fixing this, the request in the OP worked just fine.
Sorry.